# Regex match everything after n-th of decimalin yahoo pipes?

Tags: regex, expression, pipe, yahoo

Hello Im using yahoo pipes and I need some help. Im trying to match everything after the second digit of a random number.

Example:

25.6444841218545 I need to match "44841218545", so the ouput will be "25.64"

or

544.012 I need to match "2", the ouput will be "544.01"

thanks. I really need some help with this.

Comment: `[^\.]*\.\d{2}`, perhaps? Not sure if regexes are good for this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Given the poor description of the data you are trying to search across this is the best guess I can give:

```
(\d+\.\d{0,2})
```

Broken down:

```
(            # Capture
    \d+      # More than one digit
    \.       # Followed by a literal dot (.)
    \d{0,2}  # And between 0 and 2 more digits (incase the random number is truncated).
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I do agree that @Lego Stormtroopr 's answer is the best way to do what you are tying to accomplish, however to match according to your description in your question, you could do this:

```
var str = "25.6444841218545";

var result = str.replace(/([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]*/, "$1");

console.log("result = "+result);
```

Output:r

```
result = 25.64
```